# Turn on and turn off LED with serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I wrote program in C# winform.  I want to when operation is successful, LED will be turn on. I know that I must use this code:

```
serialport1.open();
serialport1.EnableDtr=true;
serialport1.close();
```

but before program is running, LED was turned on.  I set ReceiveBuffer to low , in Device Maneger.but didn't work and led is turn on.

Code from comment:

```
private void btn_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true) {
    serialPort1.Close();
  }
  try {
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    lblError.Text = "success";
    lblError.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    serialPort1.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the whole code if its possible?

Comment: Which Micro controller board you are using?

Comment: private void btn_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {

                serialPort1.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                    lblError.Text = "success";
                    lblError.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    serialPort1.Close();
                }

Comment: i didn't use microcontroller. my board include: led, resistor

Comment: which com port are you using?